# Magento System and Exception Log not working

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, log, debugging

I have exhausted every trick in my book. Magento will not log anything at all, to debug I inserted two log calls in `index.php`

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    Mage::log("WOOOOPIE");
    error_log("Go sell your fur");
}
```

- php error_log works and logs to /var/log/apache2/error.log
- {{Magento dir}}/var/log/system.log and exception.log are empty.
- In the Admin panel, Under Configuration > Developer, I enabled profiler and error logging.
- The entire var directory is owned by www-data and chmod'ed 777, I checked `ps aux`  and envvars to confirm apache is running as www-data.
- All caches were cleared repeatedly, then disabled.
- index.php has the default of `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` set.

Here are the permissions of system.log, I had to `touch` it myself.

```
namei -ml /var/www/nslocal/var/log/system.log`
f: /var/www/nslocal/var/log/system.log
drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x root     root     var
drwxrwxr-x root     www-data www
drwxrwxr-x www-data ci       nslocal
drwxrwxrwx www-data ci       var
drwxrwxrwx www-data ci       log
-rwxrwxrwx www-data ci       system.log
```

I have even tried restarting. Without the log working I can't debug why magento isn't sending emails, despite php and sendmail working properly. Do I have a ghost?

Comment: Sounds like you've tried the usual suspects that I'm aware of (although chmod 777 is using a sledge hammer). Do you have interactive debugging working? It might be useful to step through the code and see at which point it breaks?

Comment: I found mine in /tmp/magento/var/log/system.log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, the Mage logger will not function so early in the application spin up.

If you look at the Mage::log function itself, you'll find:

`if (!self::getConfig()) {
    return;
}`

As Mage::getConfig() will return null until the application's config is initialised later on inside the Mage::run() function, the Mage::log function will exit without doing anything when called from index.php.

To test the logging is actually working, try placing your test later on, perhaps in Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::dispatch which works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't believe that all my modules and Magento are so quiet that I didn't get a single error or exception throughout the entire painful metadebugging process.